# ROCR package not available for R 3.4.4

Tags: r

I'm trying to install ROCR package using command install.packages("ROCR"), but it gives the following error:

```
Warning in install.packages :


 package ‘ROCR’ is not available (for R version 3.4.4)
```

And the package doesn't appear in my list of packages. I also tried installing it from the install option in the "Packages" window, but it didn't work either. 
Do you know how I can fix this? I have also selected all repositories from setRepositories().

Thanks,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I deal with "package 'xxx' is not available (for R version x.y.z)" warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa)

Comment: Update R.If you go [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ROCR/index.html), it depends on R>=3.6

Comment: I read this question, but the answers didn't help

Comment: Update R and update with what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you cannot update your R (maybe the risk of disruption in your older R packages and codes), you can follow these steps:

1. Download the `tar.gz` format from CRAN (https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/ROCR_1.0-11.tar.gz).
2. Open the `tar.gz` file with your Archive Manager.
3. Delete `MD5` file to prevent checksum Errors.
4. Open the DESCRIPTION file and change the line `Depends: R (>= 3.6)` to `Depends: R (>= 3.1)`.
5. Save the modified DESCRIPTION and update your `tar.gz` file.
6. Open RSTUDIO and use the `install` button from `Packages` tab. `Package Archive File (.tar.gz)` in the `Install From` dropdown menu and find the modified `tar.gz`
   from `browse`, and push `install` button. Or simply use `install.packages("~/ROCR_1.0-11.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")` .

Although almost always it works fine, you should know without an `MD5` checksum you risk yourself with security issues. However, we can almost always trust CRAN packages.